# What is the name of this geometric figure

Tags: geometry, terminology

Consider four lines $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ pairwise parallel:
$X_1$ is parallel with $X_2$ and $Y_1$ parallel with $Y_2$. The four intersection points form a square.
Does this figure have a known name ?

[image]

Same question when the intersection points form a diamond:

[image]

I thought about calling them **legged square** and **legged diamond**.

Answer (score 1):

Square and diamond seem bad because they suggest they depend on the orientation of the figure and/or the distance the parallel lines are apart from each other.

Why not just "intersecting parallel pairs"?

If you really want to use the shape of the middle region to play a role in the name, you can say something abbreviated like "square intersecting pair" or "rectangular intersecting pair" or "rhombus intersecting pair". (Parallelogram intersecting pair would be a bit redundant.)